# Remove trailing backslash from msbuild batching Directory property

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to get an exec task inside an msbuild script to work and have found a very annoying issue. The exec command is sweet except that the process I'm running (Ncover.Console.exe) can't handle a backslash at the end of a directory name.

To illustrate with a snipped example, the following works:

```
<exec command="NCover.Console.exe nunit-console.exe some.dll [snip] //w c:\out" />
```

But this fails (note the slash at the end of "c:\out"):

```
<exec command="NCover.Console.exe nunit-console.exe some.dll [snip] //w c:\out\" />
```

The reason I can't simply delete the trailing backslash is that the value is read using batching. So in the same snipped as above, it *actually* looks like this:

```
<exec command="NCover.Console.exe nunit-console.exe some.dll [snip] //w 
&quot;%(TestAssemblies.RootDir)%(TestAssemblies.Directory)&quot; />
```

So my question is how can I remove this pesky trailing backslash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use batching and still remove the backslash using transformations or property functions. Is there any special reason you don't want to use these?

Comment: Hi Amir. Can you please demonstrate how I can use transformations or property functions in my case? Please use the reply button so I can credit you with the answer and your response appears in search results. Thanks.

Comment: In Danere's answer you can see an example of how to do this with [property functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx). (It is probably not possible with [transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx) because you can only add characters there)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using MSBuild 4.0 you can use property functions as pointed out by Amir, like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TestAssembliesDirectory>%(TestAssemblies.Directory)</TestAssembliesDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
<exec command="NCover.Console.exe nunit-console.exe some.dll [snip] //w &quot;%(TestAssemblies.RootDir)$(TestAssembliesDirectory.TrimEnd('\'))&quot;" />
```

Comment: Hi Danere. Unfortunately we're using msbuild 3.5 which doesn't allow property functions. Can you think of any other method for doing this? I've investigated the MSBuildHelper class but to no avail - perhaps I'll have to write a custom task or experiment with the msbuild community task RegexReplace function.

Comment: FYI my resolution was to replace that part of the command altogether with a static property. I would've been looking into using either a <script> task, a custom task or the community tasks next. Thanks Danere and Amir for your suggestions anyway.