# How can I remove tralling backslash from $(ProjectDir)?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2013, post-build-event

I have a command line like this in my post-build event:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings "$(ProjectDir)" -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

But `aspnet_regiis` is returning a failure because the tralling `\` in the directory. Pass full name, path + web.config doesn't work either.

How can I solve this?

Comment: A workaround I often use in these situations is appending a `.` to the end of the path.

Comment: Visual auto defined paths have usually a trailing backslash. This is windows usage (even if we all know it's a bad habit, and want to fix it... but when in Rome...)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the TrimEnd function to trim the trailing slash character

```
$(ProjectDir.TrimEnd('\'))
```

I found this option in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321959/remove-trailing-backslash-from-msbuild-batching-directory-property)

Comment: thanks, I was looking if VS's variables had support to functions, like in your example

Comment: if anyone want to know more about this property functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx

Comment: Ha, as if that works! Also thanks to @jack for the further references

Comment: Anyone got an idea how this can be achieved in the Core toolchain? This seems to be MSBuild only and in my dotnet (Core 3.1) project it just returns an empty string...